# using steam API to get users inventory items

Tags: php, json, api, steam

I've been working on a site and at the moment i any trying pull the steam users items and display on a web page. I'm pretty new to this kind of stuff
this is the code i have so far:

http://pastebin.com/gHAv4Azb

and here is the link to the JSon:
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198073134556/inventory/json/730/2

Any help at all will be hugely appreciated!!

Comment: Can you tell us specifically the problem you're having? Judging from the code you linked above, you're trying to display each item's name. Is the name not being displayed properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this statement `foreach($myarrayGetInv['result'][$item['classid']] as $item_A)` to `foreach($myarrayGetInv['result'] as $classid => $item_A)` and add a conditional inside this loop `if($classid == $item['classid']) echo $item_A['name'];`

The structure you request looks like this:

```
"result": {
    "item (classid)": {
        "attribute_name": "attribute_value"
        ...
    }
}
```

The former statement will loop through each name/value pair. While, the latter will loop through each item and enables you to access the name like you intended `$item['name']`.

Its hard to debug when you suppress errors by prepending the variable with `@`.